# ConcurrentModificationException in simple game

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, jpanel, concurrentmodification

I'm programming a simple Snake game.
So, I have an update thread, executes an infinite while-loop, which updates all the GameObjects and repaints the JPanel.

```
// Run thread
public void run () {
    try {
        while (true) {
            this.update();
            this.getGamePanel().sceneShouldRepaint();

            Thread.sleep(this.getFps());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I call `myJFrame.repaint()` it's probably being executed in another thread. And when I paint, I obviously have to get the location of the objects, speed and so on... 
I know the exception comes from `paintComponent()`, because it's not being caught.
As you can see, the while loop is embedded in a try-catch.

What can I do about this?

Here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.GameObjects.Creatures.Snake.Snake.render(Snake.java:52)
    at ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.SceneHandling.Scene.renderSceneObjects(Scene.java:57)
    at ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.SceneHandling.Scene.render(Scene.java:53)
    at ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.SceneHandling.GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:53)
    at ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.SceneHandling.GamePanel.paint(GamePanel.java:30)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5106)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4890)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:812)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:41)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1672)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Thanks for your help!

**HINT**

ConcurrentModificationException is being thrown if you try to access an instance at the same time from 2 different threads. That's what I've heard about it at least.

**More Code**

```
// This is the render method in the Snake class at line 50.
// So 52 is the start of the for loop

public void render(Graphics g) {
    // We delegate the drawing to the body parts
    for (SnakeBodyPart sbp : this.getSnakeBodyParts()) {
        sbp.render(g);
    }

    this.getSnakeHead().render(g);
}

// And here the for loop from the Scene class
protected void renderSceneObjects (Graphics g) {
    for (SceneObject so : this.getSceneObjects()) {
        so.render(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: As your stacktrace clearly points out, the problem is at `ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.GameObjects.Creatures.Snake.Snake.render(Snake.java:52)` Please indicate that line in the code you have posted.

Comment: You need to post more information about this. ConcurrentModification exception usually occurs when you iterate over a collection, e.g. using a for each loop), and add or remove an element while you are iterating.
The stacktracke you posted lists `ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.GameObjects.Creatures.Snake.Snake.render(Snake.java:52)`, it would be helpful to see that method, maybe `ch.ilijatovilo.Scene.SceneHandling.Scene.renderSceneObjects(Scene.java:57)` as well.

Comment: Your hint is wrong. The most common case for that exception is when you use `List.remove` instead of `Iterator.remove`.

Comment: OK, now please indicate the line as explained in the initial comment.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have, it's the `for (SnakeBodyPart sbp : this.getSnakeBodyParts()) {` part

Comment: Does `SnakeBodyParts sbp` have access to `this.getSnakeBodyParts()` list? Does it modify it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, it has access. No, it only reads it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I modify it in the update, I would get a popup if the exception would be thrown right there.

Comment: So this really is a concurrency issue. If you run your loop in your own thread, then this would explain it. The rendering goes on in the Event-Dispatch Thread, and you concurrently modify the list in your thread.

Comment: i think the SnakeBodyParts will be changed during method render(Graphics g) -> change getSnakeBodyParts to Vector and see if a synchronized collection can prevent this exception

Comment: @JanSchmidt With Vector the same thing...

Comment: @JanSchmidt Vector cannot be expected to help here. This not about destroying the collection's invariants; it is about concurrent modification.

Comment: NSAddict, Peter Lawrey has the right advice for you. Go with that.

Comment: @NSAddict Vector was wrong what about CopyOnWriteArrayList this should handle it

Comment: @JanSchmidt You were right, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` did the trick. Please, add it as an answer so I can accept it and give you some credit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well CopyOnWriteArrayList is an answer. I will look after another solution when i have some time ...

Another Solution in awt - Based Application should be

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are changing the details which need to be rendered in another thread which this library doesn't appear to allow (I would assume most GUI libraries do not allow this)

Whenevr you change a GUI component or something you will render you need to call [SwingUtils.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) so the task will be performed in the GUI Event Thread and not concurrently in another thread.

Comment: Where would I have to call this? For the painting? I'm calling `jframesubclass.repaint()` so far, how would I implement this?

Comment: The problem is not in the repaint/render method. The problem is in the thread where it is being modifed. You need to look at all places this data structure is changed and ensure it will only be run in the GUI Event Thread.

Comment: I have a animation thread, this is the only place where I modify my variables, then when the update is done, I'm calling `repaint()` in the animation thread, and I go on doing it all again.

Comment: Call your `update` method through `invokeLater`. If that is not an option, you'll need some thread coordination mechanism.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` it just blocks the main thread.

Comment: Precisely. Either that or start inventing an elaborate coordination scheme.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I thing you misunderstood me. It's blocking the UI thread, that means the window is not responding anymore.

Comment: I don't even get a repaint anymore.

Comment: You were not supposed to run the whole loop inside `invokeLater`, but only `update`. Since your loop involves a `sleep`, it won't completely block the thread. BTW there is no chance of misunderstanding: `invokeLater`s precise purpose is to execute the `Runnable` on the GUI thread.

Comment: On the other hand, if that scenario does work for you, then the `while` loop in a separate thread should really be replaced by a scheduled task on the GUI thread alone, using Swing Timer.

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` did solve my problem. I'm aware that this probably isn't the best solution. I'll take a look at Swing Timer

Comment: COWAL solves the exception, but will not solve the issue that your rendering routine will observe the list at any arbitrary point in the midst of your `update` routine.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've tried just doing the update in the thread, same result... Completely blocks the main thread, I do a `Thread.sleep(1000/30)`, shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Obviously it depends on how much work you do in the `update` method. Maybe you really do have a case for a separate thread, but, as I said, if you want to make that solid, you need some proper coordination, like sending the thread an immutable copy of the list.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But wouldn't there be a chance of a conflict too? Btw. Baš sam vidio da si naš ;)

Comment: Tebi se vidi da si naš iz stacktracea :) If you let the GUI thread only see the copy specially made for it, there can be no conflict. The best idea would be to send this over a queue, or to explicitly enqueue a `repaint` runnable by `invokeLater`. The runnable would already have the list copy in scope (close over it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are adjusting the list in both threads you would see a problem like you mention.  If you are not able to find the 'Comodification' you could lean on the java.util.concurrent libraries.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html